# Do we ever discover who built the town in East Medusa Canyon in Green Mars?

Tags: kim-stanley-robinson, mars-trilogy, green-mars

In Kim Stanley Robinson's Green Mars, as Nirgal, Coyote, Spencer and Art return Sax Russell to Gamete after rescuing him from UNTA interrogation, the group discover an unknown, abandoned, settlement in East Medusa Canyon.

Do we ever find out who built the place?

The characters notice that its built in a Boganovist style, but Coyote rejects this suggestion due to the remote location and the fact that none of the Boganovists have mentioned such a place to him.

> The white walls of the buildings glowed eerily in the starlight, like giant soap carvings. There were some twenty buildings, and many trees, and a couple of hundred people. All carved from white stone, which Spencer identified as alabaster. The central plaza seemed to have been petrified during an active morning; there was a crowded farmer's market, and a group clustered around two men, with waist high pieces on a large board.

Shortly after leaving, they notice a bas relief and decide that it is the unknown sculptor

> "Beautiful" Coyote said  "Remember that face — if that's not a self-portrait of the sculptor, I'm much mistaken." He drove on without stopping, and Nirgal stared at the stone face curiously. It seemed to be Asian, although perhaps that was only the effect of having the snake hair pulled back. He tried to memorise the features, feeling it was someone he already knew.

It seems like the text wants us to think Hiroko, but then why doesn't Coyote just say so? He seems just as confused as everyone else.